# Remove Directory And Setup Regex Redirects

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, redirect

I have a type of URL that I need to adjust for better usability, etc... We have a non-working regex right now and we're using a WP redirect plugin called 'Redirection', which allows us to use regex to mass redirect URLs. You should know that we use a reverse proxy to send traffic to our subdomain /blog/ which is on another server.

Here is the first one:
https://www.example.com/blog/index.php/this-is-a-blog-post/

Remove "index.php" from all site urls.

so the previous url for example would be: 
https://www.example.com/blog/this-is-a-blog-post/

We are using this regex unsuccessfully to target the urls:

```
(.*?)index\.php/*(.*)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried escaping the slash after index.php?

`(.*?)index\.php\/*(.*)`

https://regex101.com/r/2BMVwO/1

Comment: That did work, thanks! Just so other people can mimic, I added the target url to be https://www.example.com/blog/$2.. So if you add it into the redirection plugin its:
Source URL: (.*?)index\.php\/*(.*)
Target URL: https://www.example.com/blog/$2